# In R- append filtered dataframes in a for loop or by using a function

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, append, filtering

I have two data frames. Df1 has two columns: an ID column for a facility and a column specifying the number of farms that have a right to use that facility. 
Df2 has 3 columns, one with the ID column for a facility, one with ID for a farm and a third with a distance between that farm and the facility. Df2 currently has too many farms listed for each facility.

What I need to do is filter out those that have a right to use the facility. There will be a different number of farms with the right to use each facility and they will always be those closest to it.

Example data below

```
DF1
  cgID number.of.farms
1    1               5
2    2               3
3    3               1
4    4               6

DF2 (EXTRACT)
cgID FarmID Distance
1   farm1   0.01
1   farm2   0.02
1   farm3   0.03
1   farm4   0.04
1   farm5   0.05
1   farm6   0.06
1   farm7   0.07
1   farm8   0.08
2   farm9   0.01
2   farm10  0.02
2   farm11  0.03
2   farm12  0.04
2   farm13  0.05
2   farm14  0.06
2   farm15  0.07
2   farm16  0.08
```

I am currently only able to achieve my goal individually for each facility using the following code:

```
tempdata1<- subset(Df2, Df2$cgID==Df1$cgID[1]) #Select farms connected to the facility
editdata1<- tempdata1[1:Df1$number.of.farms[1],] #Filter out the 5 closest farms to the facility (5 was derived from Df1)
```

I have 1300 facilities I need to do this for, so I need to run these lines for each facility and group all the filtered data into one dataframe. I've tried doing this by running a for loop or writing a function, but neither has worked yet. Below is the code that has got me closest to what I want:

```
r<- sum(Df1$number.of.farms)#number of rows needed in final dataframe
c<- ncol(Df2) #number of columns needed in final dataframe
n<- nrow(Df1) #number of rows needed to go through in the for loop
d<- data.frame()
for (i in 1:n) 
{
 tempdata[i]<- subset(Df2,Df2$cgID==Df1$cgID[i])
 editdata<- tempdata[1:Df1$number.of.farms[i],] 
 d[[i]]<- editdata 
}
do.call(rbind,)
```

Comment: Could you fix your column names for `DF2`? Or explicitly state what they are?

Comment: I've edited the column names in my original post, so hopefully this will be clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

# Change column name of DF1$number.of.farms to DF1$numfarms
DF1 <- DF1 %>%                         # %>% chains actions (verbs) together
         setNames("cgID","numfarms")   # renames columns

expected <- DF2 %>%
              left_join(., DF1, by="cgID") %>%    # merges data frames by cgID column; `.` specifies object that was piped from chaining
              group_by(cgID) %>%             # you want to perform following actions group-wise
              arrange(Distance) %>%          # sort in ascending order, use `desc(Distance)` for descending order
              do(head(.,unique(.$numfarms))) # select top N rows specified, `do` will operate group-wise
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked, although I don't understand exactly what you've done. Could you point me towards some reading that might explain?

Comment: I've added more annotation and you could look at `dplyr` documentation